# Hibernate JPA configurations not working

Tags: hibernate

I am configuring hibernate with JPA annotations. I have file called country.java with JPA annotations. I have a client file to insert value in country table. while the program runs, it is showing error like "'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection avalable" I have hibernate.cfg.xml is placed in src folder. please help me to solve this

Comment: paste your cfg so we can see if it ok

Answer (score 0):

It's a path issue; the class loader can't find your .cfg.xml.

You're probably running in an IDE where you haven't told it how to find that file.  The answer depends on your IDE.

The problem is that you assume that all is well and feel outrage that the JVM isn't behaving badly.  What this tells you is that the JVM is doing exactly what it should; it's your assumptions that need to be checked.